# Is there a way to make Period selectable in leaflet.timedimension

Tags: javascript, leaflet, wms

I use leaflet to show data for users on a map. I also use different leaflet plugins.
One of them is the [leaflet.timedimension plugin](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension) so a user can scroll through WMS layers valid at different times. But I have trouble figuring out how to make the period of [timeDimensionsOptions](https://github.com/socib/Leaflet.TimeDimension#timeDimensionOptions) selectable by the user.

I have set the period to 1 hour (`PT60MIN`), but some of my data are in 15 minutes interval (`PT15MIN`). What is the appropriate approach to let the user select the period or change the period based on the selected product?

I initialise my map like so:

```js
var map = L.map('mapid', {
        zoom: 6,
        fullscreenControl: true,
        timeDimension: true,
        timeDimensionControl: true,
        scrollWheelZoom: true,
        timeDimensionOptions:{
            timeInterval: now + "/PT48H",
            period: "PT60M"
        },
        timeDimensionControlOptions: {
            autoPlay: false,
            timeZones: ['utc'],
            playerOptions: {
                buffer: 0,
                transitionTime: 500, // 1000/1500 ~ 0.7 fps
                loop: true,
            },
            speedSlider: true,
            limitSliders: true,
            displayDate: true
            position: 'bottomleft'
        },
        center: mapCenter: [56, 10],
        minZoom: 4,
    })
```

where `period` is the parameter that I would like to change dynamically.

[I have made a MWE here](https://codepen.io/whir/pen/rNJbXdp) of what I have now, but of course, without the option to change the period (timestep of the WMS layers). I am aware that the WMS layers do not work. I use a WMS-server behind a VPN wall, but it should not matter for the part related to timedimensions I hope.

My experience with javascript and leaflet is rather limited, so probably there is plenty of examples of bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you have the value of `period` changed by the user from a dropdown or input somewhere in the HTML?

```
let user_input = 'PT60M' // Let PT60M be the default.

// Get user_input somewhere, (i.e. from a HTML dropdown, radio button, you can 
// easily test using javascript's `prompt()` before coding up a lot of html)
// addEventListener to that input and onChange, re-create the `L` object
// and return it to wherever you need it to. In your MWE it would be initMap()
// just have that function take a param for `L` and call initMap with the new 'L' from onChange when
// the user changes the time period.

L.map('mapid', {
...
        timeDimensionOptions:{
            timeInterval: now + "/PT48H",
            period: user_input // Value selected by user.
        },
        timeDimensionControlOptions: {
...
    })
```